# How to show Progress in XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, xmlhttprequest, image-uploading

I used `XMLHttpRequest` to upload the file and I want to display a LoadingView before submitting the file, but LoadingView does not appear and does not work.

I use Asp.net MVC for coding.

In JavaScript:

```
// For display Loading View
function updateProgress(oEvent) {
  if (oEvent.lengthComputable) {                            
    //Loading
  } else {

  }
}

$('body')
  .on('click', '#bUpload', function() {


    var xmlHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if (!window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      xmlHttpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlHttpRequest.addEventListener("progress", updateProgress);

    xmlHttpRequest.open("POST", '@Url.Action("****", "****", new {area = "****"})', true);                    

    xmlHttpRequest.send();

 });
```

Comment: Would you clarify this question a bit? You say you "cannot do anything", and have shown some code, but it is not clear what help you want. What problem are you having exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add Event Listeners to your xmlHttpRequest.

MDN has a very good documentation on this.

[Monitoring progress](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Monitoring_progress)

Comment: I used addEventListener but still does not display Loading View. I changed the post, please see again.

Comment: Can you define "Loading View"? Do you mean visual feedback on the screen about the state of loading?

Comment: OK, there was a problem with the code. Thank you so much

Comment: You performed all your jQuery hide & remove class actions in once :D